# how can I count number of each website when it appear in many collection?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I have a schema with each website name appear in many collection.I tried to count the number of each website but i couldn't. Can you help me?

```
const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: Number,
    link: String,
    title: String,
    sapo: String,
    publicDate: Date,
    sourceCode: String,
    text: String,
    thumbnail: String,
    tags: [String],
    category: { id: Number, name: String },
    website: { id: Number, name: String },
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways. One with `aggregate` query and second with `distinct` and `count` query. See both the approaches below and try them in mongodb shell:

**Approach 1:**

```
    db.articles.aggregate([{
        $group: {
            _id: "$website.name"
        }
    },{
        $group:{
            _id: null,
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },{
        $project: {
            _id: 0
        }
    }])
```

**Approach 2:**

```
db.articles.distinct('website.name').length
```